# Debugging javascript method parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

I am trying to simply detect that current method has which parameters so i am calling arguments in chrome developer tools while i pause execution in that method. But arguments returns [] empty array. But if i try to put some parameters inside function so this time arguments and parameters get filled. There is no anything wrong about this ?

Example:

```
function(){
  console.log(arguments);//value is []
}

function(a,b,c){
  console.log(arguments);//value is not not empty array. It contains few parameters.
}
```

I don't understand how can it be ?

Edit :

Now i check it and it works but let me tell you when it is not working.

I simply use debugger then open console and write arguments and enter. Result is [] but if i using arguments in function and i see that it is filled correctly. So why just referencing arguments in console product [] result ?

Comment: How do you call these functions? As you posted them, you don't call them and also leave no reference to them.

Comment: Are we missing some code here? Where is `arguments` defined?

Comment: @ElRonnoco - `arguments` is part of ecmascript.

Comment: a fiddle to share. http://jsfiddle.net/hrhzV/

Comment: @El Ronnoco - `arguments` is an object available inside every function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: @El ronnoco - it is built-in object

Comment: The `arguments` object depends purely on the passed-in values, not on the specified parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sorry if this doesn't answer your question... it's a little hard to understand what your actual question is...*

If you're trying to find how many arguments a function **expects**, then you can use `.length`:

```
f0 = function () { };
f1 = function (a) { };
f2 = function (a, b) { };

f0.length; // 0
f1.length; // 1
f2.length; // 2
```

Source: http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.5.1

---

If you're trying to find how many arguments a function **received** then you can use `arguments.length`. Note that it has nothing to do with the number of expected arguments.

```
f = function () {
    return arguments.length;
};

f();     // 0
f(1);    // 1
f(1, 1); // 2
```